# Batch Save a text list to individual HTML pages

Tags: html, batch-file, notepad

Does anybody know how to batch save a list of text in notepad to individual html pages?

**For example:**

London
Paris
Berlin
New York

**This would then save as**

London.html
Paris.html
Berlin.html
New York.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

from the prompt

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in (files.txt) do @echo.>"%i.html"
```

from a batch script like `makeFiles.bat`

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (files.txt) do @echo.>"%%i.html"
```

More reading:

Parse the contents of a file on http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php